# how to initialize PriorityQueue

Tags: priority-queue

I'm reading the API http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/PriorityQueue.html. I'm still a bit lost.

Which is the right way to initialize?

```
PriorityQueue(Caller caller_pq);
```

or

```
static PriorityQueue<Caller> caller_pq;
caller_pq = new PriorityQueue<Caller>();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If `caller_pq` is the variable you want to hold your `PriorityQueue` then the second one --
`static PriorityQueue<Caller> caller_pq;

caller_pq = new PriorityQueue<Caller>();`
-- is correct.

It's hard to tell what you mean by your first option `PriorityQueue(Caller caller_pq)`. If you're intending to create a `PriorityQueue` containing elements of type `Caller` (which is what I think you're intending), then no, that won't work.
If `Caller` implements `Collection` or extends `PriorityQueue` then it will make a `PriorityQueue` containing the elements in `caller_pq` (as long as you precede it with `new`).